# Django overriding settings.py OBJECT in unittest not working

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-unittest

There is Django app that uses Django Rest Framework. The settings file contains an object with the settings:

**settings.py**

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    ...
    'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_RATES': {
        'burst': '30/second',
    },
    ...
}
```

The unittest is supposed to test the throttling actually works. However none of the tools provided by Django Test module ([SimpleTestCase.settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.SimpleTestCase.settings), [override_settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.override_settings), [modify_settings](http://modify_settings)) actually work:

#### SimpleTestCase.settings

```
class ThrottlingTest(RestApiTestCase):
    def test_per_second_throttling(self):
        new_config = settings.REST_FRAMEWORK
        new_config['DEFAULT_THROTTLE_RATES']['burst'] = '1/second'
        with self.settings(REST_FRAMEWORK=new_config):
        for _ in range(0, 2):
            response = self.client.get(self.api_reverse('foo'))
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 429)  # fails, 200 != 429
```

#### override_settings

```
class ThrottlingTest(RestApiTestCase):
    new_config = settings.REST_FRAMEWORK
    new_config['DEFAULT_THROTTLE_RATES']['burst'] = '1/second'

    @override_settings(REST_FRAMEWORK=new_config)
    def test_per_second_throttling(self):
        for _ in range(0, 2):
            response = self.client.get(self.api_reverse('foo'))
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 429)  # fails, 200 != 429
```

Both methods work fine for primitive variables and lists, however fail for the object.

The docs state:

> When given a class, these decorators modify the class directly and return it; they don’t create and return a modified copy of it.

So it actually **supposed** to work.

Any clues how to handle this?

Comment: well for starters, if throttling is part of the `rest framework`, you shouldn't be writing tests for that, that's the feature of the framework and framework should contain tests for that feature.

Comment: Which type of rate throttle implementation are you using - the `AnonRateThrottle` or one of the others?

Comment: Using this implementation: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/throttling/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this actually a bug/missing feature in Django REST Framework. The settings test tools (`SimpleTestCase.settings`, `override_settings`, `modify_settings`) send out a `setting_changed` signal and rely on every component to update accordingly.

Django REST Framework *does* listen to this signal ([source](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/throttling.py#L68)), but this has no effect in on the throttle rate because the throttle rate is a class attribute ([source](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/throttling.py#L68)).

That being said, I agree with @Aarif that this does not need to be tested because DRF itself has tests covering this feature.

Also, note that you are modifying the existing `REST_FRAMEWORK` settings dictionary. Create a copy instead:

```
new_config = settings.REST_FRAMEWORK.copy()
```